# netbeans java code exits with exit code 1 with no apparant reason

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, runtime-error, exit-code

the first class is this

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project  Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package logical.conundrum;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author Tuvanen Kiruitsu
*/
public class LogicalConundrum {
   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static int [] RNG_OUT;
    public static String[][] inv;
    public static float hp;
    public static int[] Room;
    public static int RNG_SET; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inv = new String[5][5];
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want > ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sc_in = input.nextInt();
        int loop_1 = sc_in;
        int sc_out = sc_in++;
        RNG_SET = sc_in++;
        RNG_OUT = new int[sc_out];
        RNG_OUT[0] = 0;
        RNG.RNG(); /fails here

        for (int a = loop_1; a >= 1; a--){
            System.out.println (RNG_OUT[a]); 
        }
    }
}
```

and the second one that the first one references

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package logical.conundrum;

/**
*
* @author Tuvanen Kiruitsu
*/
public class RNG {

    /**
     *
     */
        static int rng[];
        static void RNG(){
            int RNG_SETUP = LogicalConundrum.RNG_SET;
            rng = new int[4];
            for (int c = RNG_SETUP; c >= 1; c--){
                simulateRNG();
                LogicalConundrum.RNG_OUT[c] = rng[2]; //fails here
        }
    }
    static int simulateRNG(){
        byte y = 1;
        tickRNG(y);
        y--;
        tickRNG(y);
        return rng[2];
    }
    static void tickRNG(byte y) {
        rng[0] = (byte) (5 * rng[0] + 1);
        boolean c = (rng[1] & 0x80) != 0;
        boolean z = (rng[1] & 0x10) != 0;
        rng[1] = (byte) (2 * rng[1]);
        if (c == z){
            rng[1]++;
        }
        rng[2+y] = (byte) (rng[1] ^ rng[1]);
    }
}
```

and regardless of what i put in it always returns this

> run:
>
> How many numbers do you want > 10
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
>
> at logical.conundrum.RNG.RNG(RNG.java:23)
>
> at logical.conundrum.LogicalConundrum.main(LogicalConundrum.java:32)
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)

the code always exits like this 
I don't know what whent wrong don't know how to fix it any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Your `for` loop is incorrect. Arrays are 0 based, so you need to iterate from `RNG_SETUP - 1` to `0` instead of `RNG_SETUP` to `1`

Comment: `RNG_SET` will be the number entered +2 (because you use the ++ operator on ` sc_in` in `main()`). It's probably what is causing the problem. Use `+ 1`  insetad of `++`

Comment: @litelite That is incorrect. RNG_SET will be the number entered +1 because the `++` operator happens after the assignment.

Comment: @lucasvw Oops, true that. But it is still a problem

Comment: @litelite `++` is the increment operator

Comment: @lucasvw I want the for loop to stop at 1 as I want the last number given to be 0

Comment: Then you need to iterate from `RNG_SETUP - 2` to `1`, because of the weird increments you're doing in the main class, RNG_OUT has size 10, and RNG_SETUP == 11

Comment: `int RNG_SETUP = LogicalConundrum.RNG_SET;`

Comment: `int sc_out = sc_in++;
        RNG_SET = sc_in++;
        RNG_OUT = new int[sc_out];`

Comment: @RyanHarrison I can read the code you posted in the question just fine. That code means `sc_out` is equal to `sc_in` and `RNG_SET` equals `1 + sc_in`. The `++` operator happens after assignment.

Comment: If you want it to happen before, you  need to use `int sc_out = ++sc_in; RNG_SET = ++sc_in;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your input 10 your array will be size of 10. In `RNG.RNG()` loop you want to start from index 11 what causes out of bounds exception. Change this line:

```
int RNG_SETUP = LogicalConundrum.RNG_SET;
```

to

```
int RNG_SETUP = LogicalConundrum.RNG_OUT.length - 1;
```

Also there is a problem inside the last loop again index out of bounds. Change this:

```
for (int a = loop_1; a >= 1; a--){
```

to:

```
for (int a = RNG_OUT.length - 1; a >= 1; a--){
```

If you are looping over array then you should always use length of array as the limit instead of some variable. If you intend in your code to loop over entire array then you should change your limits inside of loops to `x >= 0`.

Comment: it works now but spams '0' the given number of times -1

Comment: Change `LogicalConundrum.RNG_OUT[c] = rng[2]` to `LogicalConundrum.RNG_OUT[c] = rng[1]` . Is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes it does but the numbers need to stay positive 
`output:` `3`
`15`
`62`
`-8`
`-29`
`-116`
`48`
`-63`
`4`
`19`
`0`

Comment: So there is something wrong with the code logic. I don't know how `tickRNG` should work. Read about debugging and debug your code by yourself.